# php and javascript in heredoc

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have this script inside a heredoc, where I'm trying to parse a json to a table, which is actually working if I don't exagerate it. The script itself is divided in two parts and comunicates with two different public functions in php. The first part reads the json from another table using a catches every session. the second part is trying to catch all the actions made on that specific session. It might sound a bit complex, but the second part is not working. Where I go from javascript to php and back to javascript. 
The part that is not working is:

```
var tblRow = '<tr><td>{$this->obj->display_ses('logs',
''+item.sesion)}</td><tr>
```

This is the part where it show how many actions were performed inside that session, but  "item.sesion" shows as **0sesion**, when I try to catch the output.

```
<script> $('#alllogins tbody').html(''); var myObject = {$this->obj->display_mysql_data_rows("logins.id as id,logins.ip as ip,logins.sesion as sesion, logins.country as country,logins.data as data,logins.user as user,admin.emri as emri, admin.mbiemri as mbiemri", "(logins,admin)","$str ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage")}; $.each(myObject, function(i, item) { var tblRow = '<tr><td>{$this->obj->display_ses('logs', ''+item.sesion)}</td><td>'+item.ip+'</td><td>'+item.country+'</td><td>'+item.data+'</td></tr>'

$(tblRow).appendTo('#alllogins tbody'); });
</script>
```

And this is the php function that returns the number of actions performed inside the given sesion.

```
public function display_ses($db, $str) { $r = mysql_query("SELECT *
from ".$db." WHERE session='".$str."'"); $num_rows =
mysql_num_rows($r); return $str; }
```

The "return $str" shows **0sesion**. So as I see it, the variable in javascript is not being **passed** in php.

When I change

```
{$this->obj->display_ses('logs', **''+item.sesion**)}
```

to

```
{$this->obj->display_ses('logs', **item.sesion**)}
```

the output shows the string **itemsesion**.

Comment: Don't you know where to use blockquotes and code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

In a string or heredoc, only ordinary variables and object references are expanded, not function calls.  Instead of using a heredoc, you should switch in and out of PHP mode, e.g.

```
?>
w = '<tr><td> <?= $this->obj->display_ses('logs', ''+item.sesion) ?> </td><tr>
```

Or if they're just short bits, you can use PHP string concatenation:

```
echo '<script> $("#alllogins tbody").html(""); var myObject = '.
     $this->obj->display_mysql_data_rows("logins.id as id,logins.ip as ip,logins.sesion as sesion, logins.country as country,logins.data as data,logins.user as user,admin.emri as emri, admin.mbiemri as mbiemri", "(logins,admin)","$str ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage").
     "</td><td>'+item.ip+'</td><td>'+item.country+'</td><td>'+item.data+'</td></tr>'";
```